# Volume of intersection of the $n$-ball with a hyperplane

Tags: euclidean-geometry, volume

Let $\mathcal{B}_n$ be the $n$-ball of radius $r>0$ and centre $\mathbf{x}_0$, i.e., $\mathcal{B}_n=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon \|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\| \leq r\}$.

The volume of $\mathcal{B}_n$ is given by 
$$
V_n(r)=\frac{\pi^\frac{n}{2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)} r^n.
$$

Moreover, let $\mathcal{H}:\mathbf{w}^\top\mathbf{x}+b=0$ be a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to find the volume of the fraction of $\mathcal{B}_n$ "cut" by $\mathcal{H}$.

If $d$ is the distance between the centre of the ball, $\mathbf{x}_0$, and the hyperplane, $\mathcal{H}$, then the desired volume,$V_\mathcal{H}$, is

$$
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } d\ge r, \\[8pt]
\dfrac{V_n(r)} 2 & \text{if } d=0, \\[8pt]
0 < V_{\mathcal H} \le V_n(r) & \text{if } d<r.
\end{cases}
$$

That is, if $d< r$, the desired volume is given as $V_\mathcal{H}=q(\mathbf{w},b,\mathbf{x}_0,r)V_n(r)$. I would like find this $q$ as a function of $\mathbf{w}$, $b$, $\mathbf{x}_0$, and $r$. I need to use this formula in a computationally expensive process, thus I need it to be "cheap". Any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: Slicing the sphere isn't as hard as you might think, it's just a lower dimensional sphere with a radius you can determine based on $b$, so it's going to be something of the same quality. You just need to compute the new radius using the Pythagorean theorem iirc.

Comment: What kind of volume you mean the plane "cuts"? $n$- or $n-1$-dimensional? So the set is the intersection of the ball with the hyperplane ($n-1$-d), or with the half-space (either of them) defined by the hyperplane ($n$-d)?

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky, I mean the $n$-dimensional volume. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AdamHughes, excuse my ignorance, but what you said is that we can consider the desired volume as a lower-dimensional sphere? So, after "cutting" with the hyperplane, we get another (lower-dimensional) sphere?

Comment: @nullgeppetto The typical example is the $2$ sphere's equator which is a circle, so you just figure out the radius and compute the circumference of the circle. The same geometry holds in higher dimensions (this is easy to prove). So you just adapt accordingly, very direct way to get what you want. But if you're cutting with a lower dimensional space, the volume is $0$ anyways, so that's really not as interesting a question.

Comment: @AdamHughes, you're right! So, I guess that I need to find a formula for the new radius each time I go to a lower dimension? Something like $r_{n-1}=f(r_n)$?

Comment: @nullgeppetto yes, and it's easy, you just draw a picture and see that it depends on how far the plane is from the origin and the radius of the original sphere, that gives you two sides of a right triangle (the radius is the hypotenuse, the distance from the origin is one leg) then compute the new radius as the third side, et voilà! You are done!

Comment: @AdamHughes, thank you so much for your help! I needed that boost! Would you mind if you checked the answer, as soon as I add it in the OP? If that's ok, I will let you know with a comment here. Thanks again!

Comment: @nullgeppetto Looking down I see Yongyong's answer is substantially the same as mine. I would just look at his and give him credit for typing the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
Look at this picture, for the distance $d$, you can use the formula $d=|w\cdot x_0+b|/|w|$. Now $r_1=\sqrt{r^2-d^2}$. Then the volume (the red part) is just the integration of the volume of the interface $S_1$ with radius $r_1$ to the interface with radius $r$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I get your point. Also, I would like to find the volume for an arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @nullgeppetto I think the formula is valid for all $n$, but it is not possible to draw a picture for $n\geq 4$, so this is only some intuition for which we can "imagine".

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your answer? I don't really understand the last sentence of it? Could you please add some formulas to help me? Thanks!

Comment: Now you have at least the radius $r_1$ and $r$. For $n=2$, the volume of the interface is from $2r_1$ to $2r$, so your volume of the red part is $\int_{r_1}^r 2s ds$; for $n\geq 3$, the volume of an $n-1$ dimensional ball with radius $s$ is $S(s)=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}s^{n-1}$, then your volume of the red part is $\int_{r_1}^{r}S(s)ds$.

Comment: Does this volume come to a closed form? Does it make it easier the fact that I just want the ration between the volume of the "cut" sphere and the whole sphere?

Comment: It's another question to compare the ration... just try to integrate the terms, they are just power functions and have antiderivatives...

Comment: You are right. I assume that it will eventually be simplified. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to compute the $n$-dimensional volume of the intersection of the half-space with the ball.

First of all, reduce the problem to a "standard form".
Suppose $\mathbf e_1,\dots,\mathbf e_n$ is the orthonormal basis in $\mathbb R^n$,
and $\mathbf e^1,\dots,\mathbf e^n$ is dual to it.
Move and rotate the space that the half-space becomes

$$\{\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^n : \mathbf e^n(\mathbf x) = x^n \ge 0\}$$

and the ball's center

$$\mathbf r_0 = - \lambda \mathbf e_n \text{ where } 0 \le \lambda \le r$$

The ball now becomes

$$(\mathbf x + \lambda \mathbf e_n)^2 \le r^2$$

In coordinate form

$$|x^1|^2 + \cdots + |x^{n-1}|^2 + |x^{n} + \lambda|^2 \le r^2$$

$$|x^{n} + \lambda|^2 \le r^2 - |x^1|^2 - \cdots - |x^{n-1}|^2$$

The volume $V'_n$ is just the part of the ball contained in the half-space defined by the $n$-th coordinate hyperplane (i.e. above it).
And may be computed as the integral of the function

$$f(x^1, \dots, x^{n-1}) := x^{n} = \sqrt{r^2 - |x^1|^2 - \cdots - |x^{n-1}|^2} - \lambda$$

over the $n-1$-dimensional disk/ball $D$, whose radius is $r' = \sqrt{r^2 - \lambda^2}$. So

$$V'_n = \int_D \sqrt{r^2 - |x^1|^2 - \cdots - |x^{n-1}|^2}dx^1\dots dx^{n-1} - \lambda \int_D dx^1\dots dx^{n-1}$$

$$V'_n = \int_D \sqrt{r^2 - |x^1|^2 - \cdots - |x^{n-1}|^2}dx^1\dots dx^{n-1} - \lambda V_{n-1}(r')$$

This integral, like for the case of the volume of the whole ball, may be reduced to $n-1$-dimensional version.
And thus may be computed by a recursive formula.